# Google Apps Script Image is not showing in Html file

Tags: google-apps-script

i have an image in google drive using apps script i want to get the image from google drive and then show that image to an html file how can i do it

"https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1vIicLiLcLvsDgXMkocwjC5z-qYjpNml7"

I tried several times but image is not showing, but before it worked, I checked the sharing option too, but don't get the result,

when i directly paste this link on web browser the image is displaying, I want the image to display in img tag.

Comment: I like to convert them to data uri's and the past them into the src=""